# Custom installer for windows C# .net project

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

Are there any installer makers that would allow me to create an installer that can add a Scheduled task to the Windows Task Scheduler?

Our product is a web application that uses IIS/Application pools and MSSQL. We are currently using InstallShield and a some batch and powershell scripts to do what we want but we have found that InstallShield is hard to use. Our InstallShield Installer installs the product and the batch files to the install directory and calls them at the end of the installer.

Ideally we would like to be able to Create the IIS applications(with custom settings), Create a windows network share, Setup the MSSQL database, and add the tasks to the task scheduler using the installer. If this isn't possible we would at least like an install tool that would allow us to pass variables from input fields to external scripts and programs easier than install shield.

Do you have any information on install tools that would be able to do any of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) if you're looking for something paid, easy to use and good customer support, [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) if you're looking for something free. The latter two are a bit harder to use because they're scripted, but can pretty much do anything.

EDIT: okay, since I'm using Advanced Installer, I'll give you a bit more detailed description as to what it can do, relevant to what you need:

- it's able to do IIS app installs and is able to run scripts against MSSQL databases, it has dedicated UIs for configuring both
- not sure about the windows network shares, you'll have to ask around the Advanced Installer forums for that
- it can install scheduled tasks, has dedicated UI for that too